# Creating a class in Python 3 "Takes no parameters" error

Tags: python-3.x

I'm leaning python and tried this code to test my 1st bit of OOP coding but I'm not sure how to fix this pesky error. This example of from Learning Python by mark Lutz 4th edition - Page 650. Any ideas?

```
#File person.py (start)

class Person:
    def __int__(self, name, job=None, pay=0):
        self.name = name
        self.job = job
        self.pay = pay

bob = Person('Bob Smith')  #test the class
sue = Person('Sue Jones', job='dev', pay=100000)
print (bob.name, bob.pay)
print (sue.name, sue.pay)
```

Yeilds the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "FILELOCATION/person.py", line 8, in  
bob = Person('Bob Smith')  #test the class
TypeError: object.**new**() takes no parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've misspelled `__init__` as `__int__`.  Does the error make sense in light of this?

Comment: Oh dear god, that was the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I got you covered, there was a time restriction (10 min or so) on accepting the answer.